# how to get input id from multiple google map autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google map autocomplete. I have multiple address picker in a single form which is shown in the bellow image:

[image]

I have added two extra custom address with the result of google map autocomplete which is shown in the bellow image:

[image][image]

The code to add extra custom address is given bellow:

```
    if (AType == "Home")
                            icss = "pac-icon icon-home";
                        else if (AType == "Office")
                            icss = "pac-icon icon-office";
                        else
                            icss = "pac-icon icon-other";
$(".pac-container").append('<div class="pac-item cs" onmousedown="ShowMap(e);"><span class="' + icss + '"></span><span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched"></span>' + Add + '</span> <span></span></div>');
```

Same office and Home address is added with the both Pickup and droffof locaion. Now i need to know the ID of click/selected address (Custom address) picker. I have used a javascript method (onmousedown="ShowMap(e);") to get the ID. But I can't getting the expected result. Can anyone help me?

```
function ShowMap(e) {
        e = e || window.event;        
        var elementId = e.target ? e.target.id : e.srcElement.id;
        alert(elementId);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `e` variable.
That variable is defined somewhere else (in the global scope), otherwise you will get an error:

> This example shows the error if you don't have the `e` variable defined:

```js
function ShowMap(e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

```html
<div id="areasearch" class="pac-item cs" onmousedown="ShowMap(e)">a</div>
```

If you want - you can pass the current element you just clicked using `this`, and this way it's easy to get the `id` of that element:

```js
var e;

function ShowMap(el, e) {
  console.log(el.getAttribute('id'))
}
```

```html
<div id="areasearch1" class="pac-item cs" onmousedown="ShowMap(this, e)">a</div>
<div id="areasearch2" class="pac-item cs" onmousedown="ShowMap(this, e)">b</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer